# Possible to load block view as popup

Tags: views, theming, blocks

I currently have a content type to add locations to the leaflet map and a view for the map itself that shows all locations added. I also have another view that grabs that location data and it currently loads in the bubble popup. Is there a way to actually load a block view of the location data as a popup on the left side of the map?